# Ajuda com um código de javascript (Iniciante)

Tags: javascript, for

Me passaram um exercício mas quando envio para saber se está certo eles me falam que está errado, que não está retornando o valor correto. Pra ser mais exato eles alegam que:

**- A função somarMoedasDe25(10) deve retornar 2.5**

```
moedas = 0
function somarMoedasDe25 (quantidadeDeMoedas){
  for (let i = 0; i < quantidadeDeMoedas; i++){
    moedas = moedas + 0.25
  }
  return moedas
}
```

Porém faço testes e quando eu coloco 10 como parâmetro ele retorna certinho 2.5

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como sou iniciante, não sei ao certo se é meu código que está errado mesmo. Podem em ajudar?

Comment: Eles quem? Com o que postou não dá pra dizer muita coisa. O que sabemos até agora é que a função somarMoedasDe25(10) retorna 2.5, pelo que está na postagem. Faltam os `;` no seu JS, mas isso não deve ser um impeditivo (o erro conceitual é o JS permitir, mas aí foge do nosso alcance). Outro problema é que você inicializa `moedas` fora da função, então se fizer o teste duas vezes em seguida entenderá o problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu imagino que se você está submetendo esse código para algum teste automático, esse teste irá chamar sua função várias vezes com parâmetros diferentes.

Como `moedas` está declarado no escopo global, esse valor irá apenas ser incrementado ao decorre das chamadas da sua função, veja o exemplo:

```js
moedas = 0
function somarMoedasDe25(quantidadeDeMoedas) {
  for (let i = 0; i < quantidadeDeMoedas; i++){
    moedas = moedas + 0.25
  }
  return moedas
}

console.log('O resultado da soma de 5 moedas é:', somarMoedasDe25(5))
console.log('O resultado da soma de 10 moedas é:', somarMoedasDe25(10))
```

Você provavelmente deveria declarar `moedas` dentro da sua função para não ter efeitos colaterais:

```js
function somarMoedasDe25(quantidadeDeMoedas) {
  let moedas = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < quantidadeDeMoedas; i++){
    moedas = moedas + 0.25
  }
  return moedas
}

console.log('O resultado da soma de 5 moedas é:', somarMoedasDe25(5))
console.log('O resultado da soma de 10 moedas é:', somarMoedasDe25(10))
```

Você também poderia retornar `quantidadeDeMoedas * 0.25` ao invés de utilizar um `for`, isso faz parte do exercício?

Comment: Sugestão seria fazer o console.log duas vezes com o mesmo valor (10) no seu exemplo, pra ficar mais evidente o efeito colateral. De qq forma, já está dado o +1

Comment: Obrigado, era isso mesmo. Sim, faz parte do exercício utilizar o "for". Só não entendi muito bem porque o resultado teu diferente declarando a variável no escopo global.

Comment: @Todeshine no global ela é zerada só na inicialização do código, e só vai aumentando. Dentro ela inicia sempre em zero a cada chamada da função.

Comment: @Todeshine, é porque a sua variável não é zerada quando você invoca a função pela segunda vez, ela está carregando o resultado da função anterior.

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaah, agora entendi. Muitíssimo obrigado!

Comment: @Todeshine você pode marcar a resposta como aceita clicando no V verdinho do lado dos pontos assim que passar o tempo mínimo do sistema.

Comment: @user140828 você tem algum site ou software em que eu possa testar meus códigos sem que possa dar esse tipo de erro? Eu estava utilizando o site https://playcode.io/

Comment: @Bacco tudo bem, obrigado! Sou novo aqui, ainda não sei mexer muito bem.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que você está procurando @Todeshine, o erro estava no código, não no site, o resultado será o mesmo.